# MySQL trigger matching a field across tables

Tags: mysql

I need to create an after insert trigger that increments a field in a different table where the id = the user_id field from the table with the trigger. I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update-notify`
AFTER INSERT
ON `notifications`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE users
SET notify = notify + 1
WHERE id = notifications.user_id
```

But got `Unknown column 'notifications.user_id' in 'where clause'`

How can I match the fields across tables in this trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NEW` for the table record that triggered the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update-notify` AFTER INSERT ON `notifications`
FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE users
  SET notify = notify + 1
  WHERE id = NEW.user_id
```